# Why rxjs epic not worked?

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-observable

tell me please what is the problem, operator zip follows conditions, by lose race, why?

```
   export default (action$, state$) =>
      race(
        zip(
          action$.pipe(ofType(stateImmediate)),
          action$.pipe(ofType(afterChainHook))
        ).pipe(
            ignoreElements()
          )
      ,
        action$.pipe(
          ofType(afterChainHook),
          pluck("payload"),
          withApplications(state$),
          map(mergeApps),
          map(updateApp)
        )
      );
```

Comment: Can you describe a little bit more what are trying to accomplish?

Comment: If the `zip` observable never emits - because the elements are ignored - it will always lose.

Comment: In fact of the matter is that zip passes